# I want to add a new paragraph between two existing paragraph in word file using python docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

**In my word file I have**

> My first paragraph
>
> My second paragraph
>
> Third paragraph
>
> Fourth paragraph
>
> fifth paragraph

**My Code**

```py
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_BREAK

document = Document('E:\\world\\2.docx')

paragraphs = document.paragraphs

paragraphs[2].runs[-1].add_break(WD_BREAK.LINE)

document.add_paragraph('new para between existing one ')

document.save('E:\\world\\2.docx')
```

**After the execution I get**

> My first paragraph
>
> My second paragraph
>
> Third paragraph
>
> Fourth paragraph
>
> fifth paragraph
>
> new para between existing one

**But I want output as**

> My first paragraph
>
> My second paragraph
>
> Third paragraph
>
> new para between existing one
>
> Fourth paragraph
>
> fifth paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert the paragraph instead of adding it. See [this documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#adding-a-paragraph) for reference. Also more info about paragraph objects [here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html).

Note, you might need to change the `[5]` I used depending on the actual contents of the `.docx` you're editing.

```py
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_BREAK

document = Document('E:\\world\\2.docx')

paragraphs = document.paragraphs

paragraphs[2].runs[-1].add_break(WD_BREAK.LINE)

paragraphs[5].insert_paragraph_before('new para between existing one ')

document.save('E:\\world\\2.docx')
```